# How to select n equally spaced rows from Dask dataframe?

Tags: python, bigdata, dask

I have a number of parquet files, where all of the chunks together are too big to fit into memory. I would like to load them into a dask dataframe, compute some results (cumsum) and then display the cumsum as a plot. For this reason I wanted to select equally spaced subset of data (some k rows) from the cumsum row, and then plot this subset. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```py
slices = 10  # or whatever
slice_point = int(df.shape[0]/slices)

for i in range(slices):
    current_sliced_df = df.loc[i*slice_point:(i+1)*slice_point]
```

and do whatever you want with the current slice

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `df[serie].sample(...)`([doc](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.sample)) would allow you to avoid to code the way of selecting a representative subset of rows.